# Folioreader error in android studio | Cannot Open epub file it needs storage access ! |

Tags: android, android-studio, github, epub

When I run the code the folioreader screen appear for a second then it disappears and this message appears

[image: The toast message]

- Java Code

```
public class PdfReader extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_reader);

        FolioReader folioReader = FolioReader.get();
        folioReader.openBook("file:///android_asset/test.epub");
}
}
```

- Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

FoilioReader does not support scoped storage and always requests `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` [here](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android/blob/2ef9269964ec48b4c20cb81d5f77d6760f6300f4/folioreader/src/main/java/com/folioreader/ui/activity/FolioActivity.kt#L285-L297).

If you are targeting Android 11+ I'm afraid your only options are finding a different reader or fixing storage access in FolioReader yourself.